# Python xgoogle library - site specific search

Tags: python, xgoogle

I am using the xgoogle python library to try to search as specific site.  The code works for me when I do not use the "site:" indicator in the keyword search.  If I do used it, the result set is empty.  Does anyone have any thoughts how to get the code below to work?

```
from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError

gs = GoogleSearch("site:reddit.com fun")  
gs.results_per_page = 50  
results = gs.get_results()  
print results  
for res in results:  
    print res.title.encode("utf8")  
print
```

Comment: This may be the reason: [Xgoogle Python library is not working any more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279934/xgoogle-python-library-is-not-working-any-more)

Answer (score 1):

A simple url with the "q" parameter (e.g. "http://www.google.com/search?&q=site:reddit.com+fun") works, so I assume it's some other problem.

If you are using pkrumins/xgoogle, a quick (and dirty) fix is to modify search.py line 240 as follows:

```
if not title or not url:
```

This is because Google changes their SERP layout, which breaks the _extract_description() function.

You can also take a look at [this](https://github.com/flepied/xgoogle) fork.

Answer (score 0):

Put keyword before site:XX. It works for me.